# C++ Subclass Overloaded Multiplication Operator Hides Base Overloaded Dereference Operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it not possible to override both `operator*()` (unary dereference operator) and `operator*(double f)` (member binary multiplication with native `double` argument) at different levels of class heirarchy?

Consider:

```
// base.h:
template<typename T>
class base {
  public:
    base(T v) : m_v(v) { }
    T& operator*() { return m_v; }
    const T& operator*() const { return m_v; }
  protected:
    T m_v;
};
```

and

```
// special.h:
#include "base.h"
class super_double : public base<double> {
  public:
    super_double (double v) : base(v) { }
    const super_double operator* (double f) { return super_double (m_v * f); }
};
```

I don't understand why the member binary `operator*` hides the dereference operator inherited from the base class, since their calling conventions are different.  The following code compiles fine if `super_double` doesn't define `operator*(double f)`, but emits an error if it does:

```
super_double q(289.3);
double d = *q; // Only good if super_double doesn't define operator*(double f)
```

It's also fine if both forms of `operator*` are defined in the template base class instead.

Why does the subclass' binary `operator*(double f)` hide the base class's unary `operator*()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ *name lookup* is a separate step to *overload resolution*. Name lookup is the process of finding a scope to go with a name.

Introducing the name `Derived::operator*` means that searches for `operator*` (or use of `*` as an operator) at a point where `Derived` is in scope, will resolve the name to `Derived::operator*`.  Then overload resolution proceeds for whatever overloads of `Derived::operator*` exist.

To have overload resolution also consider the functions that are currently named `Base::operator*`, you need to introduce those functions into `Derived` by writing:

```
using Base::operator*;
```

in the `Derived` class. That means that the name `Derived::operator*` now refers to all three of the functions, and overload resolution will select amongst them.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why the member binary `operator*` hides the dereference operator inherited from the base class

Because they have the same name. Hypothetically, perhaps C++ could have a rule that name lookup for operator functions only considers functions with the right number of arguments, but there isn't such a rule in the C++ language as is.

You can fix this the usual way: `using base::operator*;` in the derived class definition.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a better way is to implement it as a binary friend function to disambiguate it.

```
template<typename T>
class base {
  public:
    base(T v) : m_v(v) { }
    T& operator*() { return m_v; }
    const T& operator*() const { return m_v; }
  protected:
    T m_v;
};

class super_double : public base<double> {
  public:
    super_double (double v) : base(v) { }
    friend const super_double operator* (const super_double& d, double f) { return super_double (d.m_v * f); }
};

int main()
{
    super_double q(289.3);
    double d = *q;
    std::cout << d <<'\n';
}
```